# Printing a vertical histogram with cursor manipulation C++[ncurses][Solved w/o ncurses]

Tags: c++, loops, cursor, ncurses

*I've asked such question before but it was kinda misleading since i didn't include printing order.Since i learned whole concept changes with that i thought asking it again would be more approtiate.*

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int a, b, c, i;
        cin >> a >> b >>  c;

        for ( i = 0;  i < a; i++)
            cout << "*" << endl;

        for ( i = 0; i < b; i++)
            cout << "*" << endl;

        for ( i = 0; i < c; i++)
            cout << "*" << endl;
    }
```

Im aware that output is as same as:

```
for ( i = 0; i < a + b + c; i++ ){
cout << "*" << endl;
}
```

So for 2 3 1 i get:

> *
>
> *
>
> *
>
> *
>
> *
>
> *

What i want is:

```
     *

*    * 

*    *    *   //Horizontal distance between 2 shapes don't matter.
```

And it must be done in exactly in that order.Also printing of each column must be done with a seperate function.

First loop:

```
*

*
```

Second loop:

```
    *

*   *

*   *
```

Last loop:

```
    *

*   *

*   *   *
```

***EDIT:***Appereantly there was an other solution to do this without any using cursor manipulation at all.My teacher suggested that i should first store the characters in a char pointer and then print that char pointer memory row by row.Which worked just fine.

Comment: There is no "cursor" in standard C++, only an opaque output stream. You have to rethink everything.

Comment: That is why i need to do it by using ncurses or something that does the same thing.Any help please?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with ncurses. Work through the tutorials and you should be able to do this in no time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a curses program that will do it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int a,b,c,i;
  cin >> a >> b >> c;

  initscr(); // initialise curses
  int rows, cols;
  getmaxyx(stdscr, rows, cols);  // get screen size


  for (i=0; i<a; i++) {
    mvprintw(rows - 1 - i, 0, "*"); // plot at bottom column 0
  }

  for (i=0; i<b; i++) {
    mvprintw(rows - 1 - i, 1, "*"); // plot at bottom column 1
  }

  for (i=0; i<c; i++) {
    mvprintw(rows - 1 - i, 2, "*"); // plot at bottom column 2
  }

  refresh();  // update screen
  getch(); // exit when key is pressed
  endwin(); // exit curses
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this the way you are wanting to. You'll need to print a horizontal line at a time, since you can't output to the console vertically.

So first you'll need to find out how many lines you need in total, `totalLines`, which is the maximum value `a`, `b`, and `c`. Then you should iterate over each of these lines.

Within the line iterations, you need to print out the correct number of `*`s in the correct positions. The condition for whether you need to draw a point for `a` is `a >= totalLines - line` (where `line` is the current line, starting from 0 for the first line). Similarly for `b` and `c`, so you'll need 3 `if` statements with these conditions which each print out either whitespace or a `*`.

Comment: Not even with ncurses or something similar?Doing it row by row wouldn't help me at all.I abstracted my actualy program where it contains some complex drawing algorithm consits of multiple shapes not just "*".So i'm afraid either i've to do with cursor manipulation or change the whole program's itself :<

Comment: @user2362377 Well yes, you could do it with ncurses. Your question seemed to imply that you want to do it with the standard I/O library.

Comment: Rite,ty.I edited the header.Don't hesitate to post an answer if you know how to do it with ncurses :>